# Setting static file

Tags: python, django, django-templates

The problem is setting the static file.

I set the file according to the official document said.

I first created a directory called `static` in the app which my URL links to

Then I made some changes on the template.

The code is below:

```
#Structure
src
|---makesite
|---sitemaker(app)
|---templates
|        |----main.html                 
|        |----static
|                |-css
|                   |-style.css 
|-static
|-manage.py

#The settings.py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"templates/static")

#The urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from makesite.views import make_site
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^main/',make_site),
]
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, documents_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

#The File structure


#The template
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load staticfiles %}
<html>
<head>
<title>Main Site</title>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<link rel= "{% static %}'css/style.css'" href="style.css">
```

Comment: What is your `STATICFILES_DIRS` settings? When `DEBUG` is `True`, Django looks for static files in folders pointed by `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

Comment: Also can you add your project's directory structure in the question? In the question, it says "created a directory called 'static' in the **app**". **static** directory is usually created in the base folder, i.e. alongside *manage.py*.

Comment: Still don't get it right.

Comment: I created two static directory that one of it is in my app and the other is in the base folder.I still can't load the static file.

Comment: What is your `STATICFILES_DIRS` settings?

Comment: I have added some information in the article!Thanks for helping.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128904/discussion-between-gitblame-and-honesty1997).

Answer (score 0):

In the settings.py file:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

In order to load the static files in .html just use:

```
{% load static %}
```

Its always better to use {% load static %} on the top of the file.

```
{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}My Website{% endblock %}</title>
```

and suppose you have base.html and somefile.html that extends the base.html use it like this:

```
{% extends "appname/base.html" %}
{% load static %}
```

In your code:

use:

```
<link href="{%  static "css/style.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

That will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

there is error in your template code. You should rewrite link tag to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" type="text/css">
```